# Android: Cast MiniControllerFragment customization

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to customize castBackground and castProgressBarColor MiniControllerFragment attributes as explained in official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced

I use the following style for my Activity:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarNoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="castIntroOverlayStyle">@style/CustomCastIntroOverlay</item>
    <item name="castMiniControllerStyle">@style/CustomCastMiniController</item>
</style>
```

and this is CustomCastMiniController style:

```
   <style name="CustomCastMiniController" parent="CastMiniController">
    <item name="castShowImageThumbnail">true</item>
    <item name="castTitleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead</item>
    <item name="castSubtitleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption</item>
    <item name="castBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="castProgressBarColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

I am unable to build because these errors:

```
Error:(2073, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'castBackground'.
Error:(2074, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'castProgressBarColor'.
```

If I remove these two attributes in my CustomCastMiniController style app start successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes `castBackground` and `castProgressBarColor` were introduced in a later version of the Google Cast SDK, as indicated in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes):

> **Oktober 24, 2016**
>
> - Added ability to customize the style of mini controllers: added `castBackground` for setting its background color, `castButtonColor` to color all buttons used in the mini controller, and `castProgressBarColor` to color the progress bar.

So please make sure that you are compiling with the latest release of the Google Cast SDK in your `build.gradle` file (version `10.0.0` at the time of writing):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always check what's the most used [version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html). In some cases it is needed to use the latest version because some functionality is not yet implemented in an older version. You have to open the `project.properties` file of the `android-support-v7-appcompat` and change the target to latest [version](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html). After that, clean and build your project.

Answer (score 0):

In case that someone still facing the same problem today, in my situation, the issue it was a little more simple:

```
  Originally I was declaring:
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
        class="....MiniControllerFragment"
         app:castBackground="#ffffff"
```

this was causing that background be transparent, instead doing:

```
       <fragment
        android:id="@+id/castMiniController"
        class="....MiniControllerFragment"
        app:castBackground="@color/saved_color"
```

Allows you to effectively set the current color. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Define the color in your colors.xml and define it in styles.xml as @color/black instance of #000000